# Remove/Hide polygons of USA States from Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created polygon overlays in my Google Map of certain USA States. They load from an xml file when the map is initialized. I've been trying to figure out a way to remove or hide the polygon shapes once the user does a search. Here is a link to my work in progress and below that is the code I use to load the polygons during map initialization.

[Google Map with Polygon shapes of USA States](http://www.realmccoyspirits.com/test/locator)

```
function initialize() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38, -97.5),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain',
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        backgroundColor: '#eee2b2',
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
        },
    });

    map.setOptions({styles: vintagestyle});
    infobox = new InfoBox(boxoptions);
    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(
    0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(400, 400)));

    jQuery.get("js/account_locator/current_states.xml", {}, function(data) {
        jQuery(data).find("state").each(function() {
            var colour = '#835c0e';
            var points = this.getElementsByTagName("point");
            var pts = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                pts[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                }
            var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: pts,
                strokeColor: '#eee2b2',
                strokeOpacity: 0.7,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillColor: colour,
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                clickable: false
            });
            polys.push(poly);
            poly.setMap(map);
        });
    });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I've done many searches across the web but can't get anything to work. The standard way to hide polygons seems to be

```
poly.setMap(null);
```

but that doesn't work at all no matter where I place the code. Not sure if it has to do with how I am loading the polygons (during initialization), how many polygons there are, or if it has to do with how the code is constructed. I'm not a javascript expert at all so any help with this will really be appreciated. I've spent a week trying to figure this out and can't get anything to work.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you define `polys`?

`polys` should be an array.

```
var polys = new Array();
```

Then you are pushing every `poly` to the `polys` array, which is good. If you want to hide every Polygon, loop through the `polys` array and remove each Polygon:

```
for (var i=0; i<polys.length; i++) {

    polys[i].setMap(null);
}
```

Comment: I had been using:

    var polys = [];

Anyway, your code WORKED!!! Thank you so much!!! Wish I had asked a week ago. Would have saved me much pain and suffering. lol